# (tkinter) why is my laser image speeding up the more I use it with the corresponding keybind?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am currently working a space invaders inspired game for a class project and have currently experienced some problems.

whenever i keep pressing the spacebar the laser image keeps speeding up and doesn't stay the speed that i originally set it.

I wanted to see if i could make a seperate class for the laser, but i didnt know if that would help.

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import random

def main():
    screen = Tk()

    width = screen.winfo_screenwidth()
    height = screen.winfo_screenheight()
    num_allies = 4
    x_spawn_coords = [120, 340, 560, 780, 1000]

    class MovingShip:
        def __init__(self, canvas, ship_image_path, bg_image_path, laser_img_path, window):
            self.window = window
            self.canvas = canvas
            self.background_image = Image.open(bg_image_path)
            self.resized_background = self.background_image.resize((int(self.background_image.width * 0.6), int(self.background_image.height * 0.6)))
            self.background_photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.resized_background)
            self.background_identifier = self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor = 'nw', image = self.background_photo)
            self.ship_image = PhotoImage(file = ship_image_path)
            self.resized_ship_image = self.ship_image.subsample(5, 5)  # Resizing the image
            self.ship_identifier = self.canvas.create_image(560, 535, image = self.resized_ship_image)
            self.laser_image = Image.open(laser_img_path) 
            self.laser_image = self.laser_image.resize((25, 50))  # Replace desired_width and desired_height with your preferred dimensions
            self.laser_photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.laser_image)
            

            self.canvas.bind('<Right>', lambda event: self.move_ship(10, 0))
            self.canvas.bind('<Left>', lambda event: self.move_ship(-10, 0))
            self.canvas.bind('<Down>', lambda event: self.move_ship(0, 10))
            self.canvas.bind('<Up>', lambda event: self.move_ship(0, -10))
            self.canvas.bind('<s>', lambda event: self.move_ship(0, 10))
            self.canvas.bind('<w>', lambda event: self.move_ship(0, -10))
            self.canvas.bind('<a>', lambda event: self.move_ship(-10, 0))
            self.canvas.bind('<d>', lambda event: self.move_ship(10, 0))
            self.canvas.bind('<space>', self.shoot)

        def move_ship(self, dx, dy):
            x, y = self.canvas.coords(self.ship_identifier)
            new_x = x + dx
            new_y = y + dy

            # Check if the new position is within the canvas boundaries
            if 45 <= new_y <= 540 and 30 <= new_x <= 1120:
                self.canvas.move(self.ship_identifier, dx, dy)

        def move_laser(self):
            self.canvas.move(self.laser_identifier, 0, -10)
            self.laser_loop = self.window.after(10, self.move_laser)

        
        def shoot(self, event):
            self.ship_boundary = self.canvas.bbox(self.ship_identifier)
            self.tip_of_ship = (self.ship_boundary[0] + self.ship_boundary[2]) / 2
            self.centre_of_ship = self.ship_boundary[1]
            self.laser_identifier = self.canvas.create_image(self.tip_of_ship, self.centre_of_ship, image = self.laser_photo)
            self.move_laser()


    class MovingAllies():
        ally_height = 60
        ally_width = 85

        def __init__(self, canvas, image_path, x, y, dy, custom_number = None):
            self.canvas = canvas
            self.ally_image = PhotoImage(file = image_path)
            self.resized_ally_image = self.ally_image.subsample(5, 5)  # Resizing the image
            self.ally_identifier = None
            self.x = x
            self.start_x = x  # Store the starting x-coordinate
            self.y = y
            self.dy = dy
            self.start_y = y  # Store the starting y-coordinate

            self.number_label = Label(canvas, font = ('Arial', 12, 'bold'), fg = 'white', bg='black')

            if custom_number is not None:
                self.number = custom_number
            else:
                self.number = random.randint(1, 99)

        def spawn_ally(self):
            if len(x_spawn_coords) == 0:
                x_spawn_coords.extend([120, 340, 560, 780, 1000])
            random.shuffle(x_spawn_coords)
            x_coord = x_spawn_coords.pop(0)
            self.x = x_coord
            self.ally_identifier = self.canvas.create_image(x_coord, self.start_y, image = self.resized_ally_image)

            self.number_label.config(text=str(self.number))
            self.number_label.place(x = self.x - 12, y=self.start_y - 50)

        def move_ally(self):
            if self.ally_identifier is None:
                self.spawn_ally()

            x, y = self.canvas.coords(self.ally_identifier)
            if 0 <= y <= 570 and 0 <= x <= 1100:
                self.canvas.move(self.ally_identifier, 0, self.dy)
                self.number_label.place(x=self.x - 12, y = y - 50)
            else:
                self.canvas.delete(self.ally_identifier)
                self.ally_identifier = None
                self.number_label.place_forget()
                self.spawn_ally()

    def open_game():
        game_screen = Toplevel(screen)
        game_screen.geometry("%dx%d" % (width, height))
        game_screen.configure(bg = 'light grey')
        game_canvas = Canvas(game_screen, width = 900, height = 570, highlightthickness = 2, highlightbackground = "light grey")
        game_canvas.place(x = 0, y = 0, relwidth = 0.9, relheight = 0.8)
        ship = MovingShip(game_canvas, "spaceinvadership.png", "spacebg2.jpg", "bullet.png", game_screen)
        start_coords = 50

        ally1 = MovingAllies(game_canvas, "enemyimg.png", None, start_coords, 0.8)
        ally2 = MovingAllies(game_canvas, "enemyimg.png", None, start_coords, 0.8)
        ally3 = MovingAllies(game_canvas, "enemyimg.png", None, start_coords, 0.8)
        ally4 = MovingAllies(game_canvas, "enemyimg.png", None, start_coords, 0.8)
        enemy = MovingAllies(game_canvas, "enemyimg.png", None, start_coords, 0.8, custom_number = 50)

        def move_allies():
            ally1.move_ally()
            ally2.move_ally()
            ally3.move_ally()
            ally4.move_ally()
            enemy.move_ally()
            game_screen.after(10, move_allies)

        move_allies()

        game_canvas.focus_set()  # Set focus to the canvas to capture key events
        game_screen.mainloop()

    def open_intructions():
        instructions_screen = Toplevel(screen)

    def open_difficulty():
        difficulty_level_screen = Toplevel(screen)

    # Main screen
    label = Label(screen, text = "Mathematical Miseries", font = ('Helvetica', 35, 'bold'))
    label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.1, anchor=CENTER)

    play_game_button = Button(screen, text = "Play Game", command = open_game, font = ("Comic Sans", 30), fg = "grey",
                              bg = "white", activeforeground = "grey", activebackground = "white", state = ACTIVE)
    play_game_button.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.35, anchor = CENTER)

    instructions_button = Button(screen, text = "Instructions For Game", command = open_intructions,
                                 font = ("Comic Sans", 30), fg = "grey", bg = "white", activeforeground = "grey", activebackground = "white", state = ACTIVE)
    instructions_button.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.57, anchor = CENTER)

    difficulty_button = Button(screen, text = "Difficulty Level", command = open_difficulty, font = ("Comic Sans", 30),
                               fg = "grey", bg = "white", activeforeground = "grey", activebackground = "white", state = ACTIVE)
    difficulty_button.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.79, anchor = CENTER)

    screen.geometry('800x500')

    screen.mainloop()

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call `move_laser`, it creates a loop that moves the laser every 10 ms. Every time you call `shoot`, `shoot` calls `move_laster`. Thus, every time you call `shoot` you are creating a *new* loop. So, call `shoot` once and something happens every 10ms. Call `shoot` again and something happens every 10ms *twice*. Call `shoot` again and it happens three times every 10ms, and so on.

> I wanted to see if i could make a seperate class for the laser, but i didnt know if that would help.

Yes, it would help. Each instance of the laser created by `shoot` could keep track of its own canvas items and it's own `self.laser_identifier`.

Comment: so could i instead create a separate class for the laser image and potentially create 2 lists that keep track of the lasers that have been fired and ones that need to be removed so I know which lasers to .remove() from the canvas. Sorry just throwing out ideas, don't know if that made sense.